# Recent achievements reputation counter is off

Tags: bug, reputation, achievements-dialog

There are numerous posts with similar titles as this, and usually they are perfectly explainable by either removed votes, or un-upvotes etc.

In my case the recent achievements showed the following:
[image]

The number on the trophy shows as `+8` whilst the unread achievements total up to `+7`.

I checked my reputation history on my profile for the following things, but found none of them:

- Downvoted answer removed
- un-upvote of an answer

I wonder if the counter gets thrown off by me downvoting 2 answers to the same post?

As Glorfindel pointed out in the comments, it could also be due to activitiy on another site of the network.
I manually checked all accounts I have, and found no activity on them.